# Utility to reflow textarea content in browser

Tags: firefox, text-processing

Is there any Firefox extension or Greasemonkey script that would make it possible to reflow paragraphs in a `textarea` content in Forefox?

To be clear, I mean like the "Reflow Paragraph" function of Emacs bound to <kbd>◆</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, or the "Reflow Lines/Block" function of Geany bound to <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, which reformat your text so that lines are at most *n* characters long.

I would be happy if such an extension existed at all, but if there is choice, I would prefer one that makes it possible to configure the preferred line length *n*, and one that respects attempts to respect indentation like Geany does.

I would mainly use this to format the emails I send through Gmail. (Gmail does cut your lines, but it does so wherever it feels like, and you can only see the result *after* you've sent your message, with often catastrophic results in languages where one is expected to use a space before a punctuation sign.)